# Testcafe - How to use JSON response data as a variable

Tags: json, testing, automated-tests, httpresponse, testcafe

I want to add a testcafe step where I call an API GET and use something from the JSON response body as an inputted test into a field.

How can I implement this functionality in TestCafe?

I was trying to use `RequestLogger` from https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html That didn't work, it didn't make any request.

Here is the fetch that works when used in console:

```js
var SMScodeField = document.querySelector(`input#code`)

fetch(
//call the API to get the SMS code
  `https://app.website.com/api/test-helper/getLastSMS`)
  .then(response => response.json())
//use the code value as input into pre-defined field SMScodeField
  .then(data => {SMScodeField.value = data.sms[0].code})
```

I also have a working code from Cypress

```
cy.request(`https://app.website.com/api/test-helper/getLastSMS`)
  .then((response) => {
     let body = JSON.parse(response.body)
     cy.get(`input#code`).type(body._embedded.sms[0].code)
   })
```

How can I implement this behavior in TestCafe? I just need to take the `code` from JSON response when calling https://app.website.com/api/test-helper/getLastSMS and use it as an input into a field SMScodeField

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use standard nodejs code in your TestCafe test. Just use axios or node-fetch to get your data and use them later in your test.

```
npm i -D axios @types/axios
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('https://app.website.com/api/test-helper/getLastSMS')
   .then(response => console.log(response));
```

#### References:

- https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/import-third-party-modules.html
- https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround, but its possible to use node-fetch

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

didnt try it yet, but I really want to use something native to TestCafe

Answer (score 0):

In TestCafe v1.20.0 and newer, you can send HTTP requests and check their responses in your tests using the [`t.request` method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403981/reference/test-api/testcontroller/request).
Please check out the following test - it sends a request and uses JSON data from the response in a `typeText` action.

```js
fixture `Test API`;

test('Simple Test', async t => {
    const body = await t.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').body;

    console.log(body[0].email); //-> Eliseo@gardner.biz

    await t.typeText('change-this-selector', body[0].email);
});
```